# R tkrplot layout issue

Tags: r, tk-toolkit

I've got a problem with extra space being put to the right and below plots made with `tkrplot` in R, as below. I've tried changing `hscale` and `vscale`, but all that does is magnify/reduce the overall size of each plot, along with the extra unwanted space.

[image]

The code that generates these looks like this:

```
ct <- tkrplot(pane, fun)
tkgrid(ct, row = deRow, column = deCol)
```

where `deRow` is 1, and `deCol` is 1 for the first one, and 2 for the second.

Added: The function for the second plot looks like this:

```
fun = function(){
  ....
  fp2 = ggplot(df, aes(time, val, color=iPer)) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_path(aes(group = iPer))
  print(fp2)
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [***Programming Graphical User Interfaces in R By Michael Lawrence, John
Verzani***](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=J-3RBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA410&ots=MQkW2sFIUi&dq=tkgrid%20manual&pg=PA380#v=onepage&q=tkgrid%20manual&f=false) :

> ***GRID***
>
> The tkgrid geometry manager is used to align widgets in rows and
> columns. In its simplest usage, a command like
>
> *tkgrid(child1,child2,..., childn)*
>
> will place the n children in a new row, in columns 1 through n.
>
> ***...***

and guessing you want to use only one row it seems you can call a single tkgrid with both plot as parameters.

I hope this help you,

Saludos!

Comment: Saludos tambien! I have that book and have tried that, but the problem is the difference between the size of the plot and the size of the grid cell.I can't get them to agree, and it seems to depend on the monitor I'm using and possibly on the adjustable screen resolution as well. I'm running Windows 10. It looks fine on my big monitor at home, but when I put it on the laptop's own screen it's terrible, as I showed.

Comment: Hmm, i see. Well, i must apologize because i'm really a tcl'er and i cant speak in R. ;-).  but having tk in common i take the liberty of suggest to you try with the pack layout with the options side=left, fill=both and expand=1. I think this can be the simplest solution because the alternative, using grid, would imply the commands (grid) rowconfigure and (grid) columnconfigure with the parameter weight=1 and the sticky option="nsew" for the cells.

Comment: Your trying to help is much appreciated. Switching to pack from grid is a bigger change than I was hoping for because I've got a layer that builds on top of it. I hope something simpler comes along. But really, muchas gracias.